# While navigating to another page url and pages are collapsing

Tags: angular

when I click on button it is navigate to another page but its collapsing the current and navigation page
and url also not visible and both page are not properly visible please some one check and help me to fix this issue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjqEg.png)